# Converting dictionary values into a string object with a specific order

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am looking to create a function that will turn a dictionary with address values into a string value with a specific order. I also need to account for missing values (Some address wont have a second or third address line. I want my output to look like the below so that I can copy the text block, separated by a new line, into a database field.

```
name
contact
addr1
addr2 (if not empty)
addr3 (if not empty)
city, state zip
phone
```

I have the following to create the dictionary, but I am stuck on creating the string object that ignores the empty values and puts everything in the correct order.

```py
def setShippingAddr(name, contact, addr1, addr2, addr3, city, state, zipCode, phone):
    addDict = {'name': name, 'contact': contact, 'addr1': addr1,
               'city': city, 'state': state, 'zip': zipCode, 'phone': phone}
    if addr2 is True:    # append dict if addr2/addr 3 are True
        addDict['addr2'] = addr2
    if addr3 is True:
        addDict['addr3'] = addr3

    shAddr =     # This is where i need to create the string object
    return shAddr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite the function to only return the string, the dictionary is not necessary:

```
def setShippingAddr(name, contact, addr1, city, state, zipCode, phone, addr2=None, addr3=None):
    shAddr = f'{name}\n{contact}\n{addr1}'
    shAddr = f'{shAddr}\n{addr2}' if addr2 else shAddr
    shAddr = f'{shAddr}\n{addr3}' if addr3 else shAddr
    shAddr = f'{shAddr}\n{city}, {state} {zipCode}\n{phone}'
    return shAddr
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like (assuming you're using python3), an f string would work here.

```
shAddr = f"{addDict['name']} {addDict['contract'] etc..."
```

You can add logic within the {}, so something like

```
{addDict['addr2'] if addDict['addr2'] else ""}
```

should work, depending on what the specific output you were looking for was.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you may want to add new entries to the dictionary

```
def setShippingAddr(name, contact, addr1, addr2, addr3, city, state, zipCode, phone):
    addDict = {'name': name, 'contact': contact, 'addr1': addr1,
               'city': city, 'state': state, 'zip': zipCode, 'phone': phone}
    if addr2 is True:    # append dict if addr2/addr 3 are True
        addDict['addr2'] = addr2
    if addr3 is True:
        addDict['addr3'] = addr3

    shAddr = ''
    for key in addDict:
      shAddr += addDict[key] + '\n'
    return shAddr
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the part with the dictionary. You could just leave it out, right?
Then

```
def setShippingAddr(*args):
    return "\n".join([str(arg) for arg in args if arg])


s = setShippingAddr("Delenges", "Me", "Streetstreet", "Borrough", False, 
                    "Town of City", "Landcountry", 12353, "+1 555 4545454")
print(s)
```

prints

```
    Delenges
    Me
    Streetstreet
    Borrough
    Town of City
    Landcountry
    12353
    +1 555 4545454
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more pythonic solution,

```
def dict_to_string(dic):
    s = ''
    for k, v in dic.items():
        s += "{} : {}\n".format(k, v)
    return s


addDict = {'name': 'name', 'contact': 'contact', 'addr1': 'addr1', 'addr2': '',
           'city': 'city', 'state': 'state', 'zip': 'zipCode', 'phone': 'phone'}
print(dict_to_string(addDict))
```

In this case, I've used addr2, which has a blank value. If you want, addr2 to be omitted completely, then check for the value while iterating.

```
def dict_to_string(dic):
    s = ''
    for k, v in dic.items():
        if k:
            s += "{} : {}\n".format(k, v)
    return s


addDict = {'name': 'name', 'contact': 'contact', 'addr1': 'addr1', 'addr2': '',
           'city': 'city', 'state': 'state', 'zip': 'zipCode', 'phone': 'phone'}
print(dict_to_string(addDict))
```

Finally if the natural order of iterating is not what you want you can use the `OrderedDict`